# remove mysql data, cron vs Mysql Event Scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron

I am using codeigniter framework, and I want to remove some rows when one column have a specific value (e.g read =1).

Is it better to use PHP CRON, or Mysql Event Scheduler?

Comment: Depends if you need to do other things.. Also on shared webhosting the Mysql Event Scheduler is most likely disabled..

Comment: thank you, i do not want to do other things, and i'm using Hostgator shared hosting, which the best solution you think?

Comment: The one that works, if MySQL events are enabled use that otherwise a cronjob